# ios 9 remove share button from uimenucontroller and uiwebview

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, ios9, uimenucontroller

I am implementing custom UIMenuController and trying to figure out, how can I legally disable Share and Define UIMenuItems of UIMenuController in UIWebView, iOS 9".

I tried :

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender 
{
   if (action == @selector(share:))
    {
        return NO;
    }

    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

but no luck.

I put this by subclassing UIWebview as well as my View controller but no luck.

The only thing i get as the selector is `_share:` and as that is private and cannot be used I have to use another option .
Any other options or Do i need something completely Custom.

Answer (score 3):

You need to subclass UI Web View, within the subclass add this method.
Below given code will only show custom Method menu in menu controller rest will be hidden/removed. You can add menu in condition which you want to display in menu controller.

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender { 
    if (action == @selector(customMethod:)) {
        return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Will this be accepted in the app store I have a release shortly and dont want to get this rejected by the app store

Comment: @Maksud, I don't think "share..." for UIWebView can be disabled this way. Has this been tested?